# How to add ellipsis to a text widget in between two text widget in a row widget

Tags: flutter, refresh, bloc

I am in need to create a UI similar to below illustration. The second text to shrink to give space for third text in a row.

**Excepted UI**

[image: Excepted UI]

But the second text doesn't shrink whereas the third text widget shrinks

**Present UI**

[image]

I used expanded to wrap the third Text widget. It didn't help.

```dart
Row(children: [
  Container(color:Colors.lightBlue, child:Text('1one'),),
  Container(
    color:Colors.lightGreen,
    child:Text(
      '2Two2Two2Two2dbTwo2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2', 
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)),
  Expanded(
    child:Container(
      color:Colors.orange, 
      child: Text('Three3Three3Three3Three3Three3Three3Three3Three3Three3Three')
    )
  )
])
```

[Dart pad](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b?)

Comment: Try and set `maxLines` to 1 on all text widgets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the second widget with `Expanded`, instead of wrapping the third one.

**Reason**

`Expanded` widget render the child within the leftover available space,

In the above requirement the second text needs to be rendered in the left over space not the third one, Hence the second text has to be wrapped by `Expanded` not the third one.

Comment: Worked super cool. Added a edit with explanation. Mind accepting it?

Comment: done! Great edit. Makes the answer more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use expanded and flex value to distribute the whole space

```
Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  child: Text('1one'),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  child: Text(
                      '2Two2Two2Two2dbTwo2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2Two2',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  child: Text(
                    'Three3Three3Three3Three3Three3Three3Three3Three3Three3Three',
                    maxLines: 1,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Your suggestion is great when we are separating a row to widgets with proportionally sized children. But that's not my case.